# How to conditional get values on Context ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get all the notes created by a specific user. The `_context.Notes` returns all `Notes` from the table, but I just need the `Notes` where `postedBy == user_gd` where `user_gd` is the parameter of the method.

How am I able to add an if statement that checks if `postedBy == user_gd`? And return all notes of the user when done.

Database tables: postedBy = Gd of user table. **Table 1: User table, Table 2: Notes table.**
[image]

How can I implement this method so it only returns the notes with `postedBy` as the parameter

```
public IEnumerable<Note> GetNotes(Guid user_gd)
{
   return _context.Notes;
}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)  if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to achieve it and I'm completely stuck with it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Also, please do not show your code as a picture. Edit your question to replace it by code cut and pasted from the IDE. Once you have, select it and press Ctrl-K to format it as a code block.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I fixed it. I will test it now.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk My pc had problems with using System.Linq; but it works now thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Note` model should contain `PostedBy` property.

Then you can add `using System.Linq;` and use:

```
public IEnumerable<Note> GetNotes(Guid user_gd)
{
   return _context.Notes.Where(x => x.PostedBy == user_gd);
}
```